# Connect moodle to external SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, external, moodle

I have a vm with ubuntu server 14.04 running locally Moodle application, with mysql.

I am wondering if it is possible to change db, and connect moodle to SQL Server 2008, which it at another vm.

I don't care about the data (to migrate). Mainly I want to use Moodle from ubuntu server with SQL from another server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs there is a possibility to use moodle with mssql.
You need to integrate mssql php driver
which you can find [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-IE/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

quote from:[moodle org](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP)

freetds.conf should have the following structure:

```
 [global]
     host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (host name or ip of the MSSQL server)
     port = 1433
     client charset = UTF-8
     tds version = 8.0
     text size = 20971520
```

> If you want to connect to a particular instance of MSSQL you should
>   specify the instance name:

```
 [global]
     host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (host name or ip of the MSSQL server)
     instance = xxx (instance name, e.g. INST2)
     port = 1433
     client charset = UTF-8
     tds version = 8.0
     text size = 20971520
```